# .NET 6 project within Jetbrains Rider on Apple M1 fails to debug or start after updating to Rider 2022.1

Tags: macos, apple-m1, .net-6.0, rider, apple-silicon

I am working on a .NET 6 project using Rider as IDE on macOS Monterey on an Apple M1 Pro.

After updating Rider from 2021.3.4 to 2022.1 with the JetBrains Toolbox, launching the project locally fails with exit code 137.

Trying to debug, I get the following error/timeout:

> One or more errors occurred. (Started a process for debugging, but no
> CoreCLR runtime was seen to be loaded within the 00:00:16 time limit.)

I already uninstalled and reinstalled .NET 6 with Homebrew. That did not help. The only way to fix the problem was to downgrade Rider to the previous version with the JetBrains Toolbox.

Does anybody know that problem? I don't want to stick with 2021's versions of Rider forever ;-)

**Solution**

Seems to be an actual bug in Rider that should be fixed with 2022.1.1, according to this Issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-76273/Cannot-debug-azure-functions-due-to-0x80131C3C-error

**Solution Part 2**

Please note also that you have to re-install Azure Toolkit and delete the folder .AzureToolsForIntelliJ directly under your user's directory.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Comment: There is a change everything will be fixed in the upcoming Rider 2022.1.1 version. If not - create an issue (and attach logs there) using the link above

Comment: Thanks, I found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-76273/Cannot-debug-azure-functions-due-to-0x80131C3C-error right after posting this question. Thanks to both of you.